# avoiding cast to Nothing in generic method

Tags: generics, scala

```
scala> def foo[U](t: Any) = t.asInstanceOf[U]
foo: [U](t: Any)U

scala> val s: String = foo("hi")

scala> val n = foo("hi")
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to scala.runtime.Nothing$
    at .<init>(<console>:6)
    at .<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$.<init>(<console>:9)
    at RequestResult$.<clinit>(<console>)
    at RequestResult$scala_repl_result(<console>)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.tools.nsc.Interpreter$Request$$anonfun$loadAndRun$1$$anonfun$apply$18.apply(Interpreter.scala:981)
    at scala.util.control.Exce...
```

Is there a way to write #foo so that it returns an Any if 'U' is not inferred or set explicitly to a "real" type?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. The static type is `U`. If this is inferred as `Nothing`, the compiler won't allow a return value of type `Any`.

You can improve the runtime error message:

```
def foo[U: Manifest](t: Any): U = if (implicitly[Manifest[U]] == manifest[Nothing]) 
  error("type not provided") 
else t.asInstanceOf[U]
```

Or follow the Arjan's suggestion.

Comment: I would have expected that when there's a return value, Any would be inferred, rather than Nothing. I guess this is what happens when Scala sets high expectations ;-)

Comment: But `Nothing` is uninhabited. So this if U is ever inferred to be `Nothing` (which in cases like the example, of if the value of the method is unused), then it will always cause a ClassCastException (even if the result of the cast is just thrown away!). I would much rather have a compile time error. BTW, I ran into this with upgrading the jackson-databind library, and ran across this method: https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.11/ which led to runtime cast exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is that you need to always specify the generic type, with `foo[String]("hi")`. Since the generic type `U` doesn't appear in any of the parameters, it can't be inferred.

There's no way to make foo's generic parameter default to `Any` when it can't be inferred (which is never -- it can never be inferred). If you were to redefine the function as

```
def foo[U](t:U)=t.asInstanceOf[U]
```

then the following call would not compile:

```
val s:Any="Hi"
foo[String](s)
```

Answer (score 2):

From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41403287/possible-to-make-scala-require-a-non-nothing-generic-method-parameter-and-return/41403871#41403871) its better to fix foo so that it can't be called to return a Nothing type:

```
sealed trait NotNothing[-T] 

object NotNothing {
  implicit object YoureSupposedToSupplyAType extends NotNothing[Nothing]
  implicit object notNothing extends NotNothing[Any] 
}

def foo[U:NotNothing](t:U)=t.asInstanceOf[U]
```

This way, if you forget to add the type parameter, you'll get a compile-time warning:

```
f("123")  // Fails
f[String]("123")  // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether this is what you mean, but can't you just use U as type for t instead of Any?

```
scala> def foo[U](t: U) = t.asInstanceOf[U]         
foo: [U](t: U)U

scala> foo("hi")
res0: java.lang.String = hi

scala> foo(1)   
res1: Int = 1

scala> val a:Any = "hi" 
a: Any = hi

scala> foo(a)
res2: Any = hi
```

Comment: But `foo[String](a)` won't compile.

Comment: Ken is right, that doesn't compile, so my answer won't work in this case