# Possible to make scala require a non-Nothing generic method parameter and return to type-safety

Tags: scala, generics

In scala, the shit can hit the fan if the caller of a generic method omits to explicitly specify the type parameter. For example:

```
class Expression[+T] // Will have eval():T method, so +T

class NothingTest {

  def makey[T](): Expression[T] = null

  def needsBool(b: Expression[Boolean]): Unit = {}

  var b: Expression[Boolean] = null
  var n = makey()  // : Expression[Nothing]

  b=n  // Yikes.

  needsBool(n)  // :-/ Supplied Expression[Nothing] ... not a Expression[Nothing]
}
```

I'm *supposed* to supply a type parameter to `makey()` (e.g. `makey[Boolean]()` ), however in this instance I forgot, the program compiled (which, by the way, is extremely easy to do).

The program will eventually fail in `needsBool` (implementation omitted) which did not receive an `Expression[Booolean]` object - it got an `Expression[Nothing]` object instead. Scala's docs says Nothing is a subclass of all types, which seems exceptionally rude and is certain to break type safety wherever it appears.

So, to reintroduce some type-safety, can I either:

- prevent `makey` from returning Expression[Nothing] but requiring that a type parameter be provided? ([I suspect not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3157422/avoiding-cast-to-nothing-in-generic-method)), OR
- prevent `needsBool` from receiving an Expression[Nothing]?

at compile-time.

---

Update:

A fuller (compiling, but runtime failing example):

```
class Expression[+T](val value:T){ 
  def eval:T = value
}

class NothingTest {

  def makey[T](): Expression[T] = new Expression[String]("blah").asInstanceOf[Expression[T]]

  def needsBool(b: Expression[Boolean]): Unit = {
    val boolval = b.eval  // Explode! String is not a Boolean
    println(boolval)
  }

  var b: Expression[Boolean] = null
  var n = makey()  // : Expression[Nothing]. You're suppose to supply a type, but forgot.
  b=n  // Yikes.
  needsBool(n)  // :-/ Supplied Expression[Nothing]
}
```

Comment: Why did you "omit implementation"? Can you show an example of something that compiles, but breaks at runtime? I am not sure it is possible.

Comment: Because the implementation's not relevant -- its an issue about interface specification and constraints. Anyhow -- I've added a (fictitious) but runtime-failing example.

Comment: Surely, if you cast `Foo` to `Bar`, you can get all kinds of runtime failures. 
Your latest update has nothing to do with `Nothing` (no pun intended). You forfeit type safety by using `.asInstanceOf`. 
Replace your `var n = makey` with `var = makey[Boolean]`, and it'll still compile, and still fail at runtime the same way.

Comment: The issue is that makey[Int]() is of type Int, but makey() is of type Nothing -- its got nothing to do with the implementation makey or whether its internals are typesafe. As I mentioned in the question, the issue is not how to make this safe for the caller by requiring the generic parameter at compile-time. Scala loses type safety when giving a Nothing back since a Nothing is a valid parameter for everything!  Luka's answer seems like a good one.

Comment: What it has to do with implementation is I think you are mistaken assuming that the `Nothing` thingy causes the problem you are talking about. Your statement about scala losing type safety in this case is wrong: losing type safety would mean allowing you to write valid code, that compiles, but fails at runtime. This is not the case. The reason implementation you referenced is indeed not type safe, but the loss is due to the cast (which indeed isn't type safe), _not_ to the assumed `Nothingness` of the type parameter (which is).

Comment: The example does compile and and does fail at runtime. makey() returns an Expression[Nothing] (as asked, and indeed n *is* of this type). needsBool requires an Expression[Boolean], but the compiler sees nothing wrong in passing its an Expression[Nothing] which turns out not to be a Expression[Boolean]. The fact that a type-cast happens inside makey is irrelevant. Any implementation that returns an object that is both Expression[Nothing] and not Expression[Boolean] would cause the failure.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've found a somewhat hacky solution, but it works.
Create a `NotNothing` type that's contravariant in its type parameter, then provide an implicit object for both `Any` and `Nothing`. 
Now if you try to use a value of `NotNothing` with `Nothing` the compiler will complain about ambiguity. Case in point:

```
sealed trait NotNothing[-T] 

object NotNothing {
  implicit object YoureSupposedToSupplyAType extends NotNothing[Nothing]
  implicit object notNothing extends NotNothing[Any] 
}
```

Then constrain your `makey` function with the `NotNothing` type:

```
def makey[T : NotNothing]() = { ... }
```

And voila now you'll get a compile time error if you forget to supply a type!

Comment: Excellent solution. Error messages could be improved. See https://riptutorial.com/scala/example/21134/preventing-inferring-nothing